# doubleClick not working in Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I need to double click on a button using Selenium IDE. I have used below code.

```
 <tr>
<td>doubleClick</td>
<td>name=c</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried replacing the command with doubleClickAndWait also.But on replay the double click is found not happening.

I want to click on button named Save with below html code

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" name="c"/>
```

Comment: I don't see any code that you've used.. please edit your question with the same.

Comment: Why would you want to double click a `type="submit"` button

Answer (score -1):

In Java for example, that would be something like:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(yourElement).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Comment: I need to do it with Selenium IDE